# retrieving data from mysql database and inserting into sqlite and displaying in the imageview

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I have a set of images with names.I have created image table with two columns in mysql. I am inserting the images to mysql database using the following code.

```
if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE)
            {
                echo "<script>alert('Please select an image')</script>";
            }           
        else 
            {
                $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                 $name=$productname;
                $image= file_get_contents($image);
                $image= base64_encode($image);
                $qry="insert into images (products,image) values ('$name','$image')";
                $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
            }
```

For retreiving and displaying the inserted images i am using the following code.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

                 $productname = $row['products'];
                echo '<tr align="center" height="70">';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row[0];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo '<img height="200" width="200" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[1].' "> ';
                echo '</td>';
                print("<td width='100'><a href='imagedelete.php?id=$row[products]'>Delete</a></td></tr>");

            }
```

Inserting and displaying the all the images are happening correctly using the mysql database.

I tried this code to insert and retrieve and display using sqlite but didnt work.

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
String q="SELECT image FROM Product_Image where products='" + productitem + "'";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(q, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
byteImage2 = cursor.getBlob(2);
productimage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage2,0, byteImage2.length));
```

My doubts is

1. I want to retrive the images from the mysql database and insert to sqlite database.How will i do that.
2. After inserting i want to retrieve the image from sqlite database and display in the image view.How will i do this.

Please help.Code for my doubts would be helpful.

Comment: You should consider not storing the base64 encoded image in SQLite database as cursor are limited to 1Mb. Instead save the image to file system and store a reference (path, uri) to it on the database.

Comment: Sorry to say it's a waste of battery, data, storage and programming effort. Saving images in a database is a bad idea. You should only save links to the images. Secondly using base64 encode makes the data much larger than it is. You will be filling up the storage on the device very quickly. Last but not least the downloaded images may not even be used or be used only once or twice.

Comment: can u help me with the code